# Is there a performance difference between using useSelector once or multiple times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm basically wondering if there is a difference in performance, or any other pros and cons, between the following 2 code snippets. Are there any objective reasons to use one over the other, or is it just personal preference?

```
const prop1 = useSelector((state) => state.appModel.prop1);
const prop2 = useSelector((state) => state.appModel.prop2);
const prop3 = useSelector((state) => state.appModel.prop3);
const prop4 = useSelector((state) => state.appModel.prop4);
```

```
const {
  prop1,
  prop2,
  prop3,
  prop4,
} = useSelector((state) => ({
  prop1: state.appModel.prop1,
  prop2: state.appModel.prop2,
  prop3: state.appModel.prop3,
  prop4: state.appModel.prop4,
}));
```

The second option instinctively feels like it might be more performant, because it only uses useSelector once, but then I wonder if one property changing may cause more re-renders because they're all grouped together.

UPDATE:

Also wondering if this even shorter version has any pros and cons?

```
const { prop1, prop2, prop3, prop4 } = useSelector((state) => state.appModel);
```

Apologies if this is a duplicate, I tried searching but wasn't entirely sure of the terminology to search for, and couldn't see any matching examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The individual one is **much** better performance wise. Your second approach creates a new object every time the selector is called, so when useSelector compares the before and after it always looks like it has changed. As a result, your component is forced to render on every change to the redux store, even if nothing happened to prop1-prop4.

If you want to do #2, you need to make a memoized selector, so that it returns the same object if none of the individual values have changed. You can read more about memoized selectors here: https://redux.js.org/usage/deriving-data-selectors#optimizing-selectors-with-memoization

(While it's good to learn about memoized selectors, for your case i would recommend sticking with approach #1)

> Also wondering if this even shorter version has any pros and cons?
>
> const { prop1, prop2, prop3, prop4 } = useSelector((state) => state.appModel);

That's better than #2, because now it will only need to rerender when appModel changes. If the only things in appModel are prop1-prop4, then this will be basically the same as #1. If there are extra properties in appModel that you don't care about, then this may result in a few extra renders when appModel changes due to those other properties.

Comment: Thank you, this is really clear and helpful information, and all makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 2):

If prioritizing performance efficiency from top to bottom, I think it would be like this:

1. const prop1 = useSelector((state) => state.appModel.prop1);
   ...
2. const {
   prop1,
   ...
   } = useSelector((state) => ({
   prop1: state.appModel.prop1,
   ...
   })
3. const { prop1,... } = useSelector((state) => state.appModel);

Always try to return primitive values, such as `string`, `number`, `boolean`, etc. when it is possible from callback of useSelector (or use memoizing techniques, see below). Because when you return an `object` value (object, array, array-like object, etc.) from callback function of `useSelector`, it causes a new re-rendering of that component, no matter whether any state was changed in your redux tree related to those states that you returned inside of *every time* **new** object or not. So, in cases 2 and 3 you are returning a value of `object` type (assuming prop1, ... is not object type value), therefore your component's props changes always and it re-renders it self by nature of React, even if rendering happens in the parent component of that component.

So, you need somehow memoize your `object` values to achieve better app performance, which helps to avoid unnecessary re-renderings. So, to do it you can pass `shallowEqual` function as a second paratmeter to useSelector from `react-redux` library. Of course, you can write your custom function to compare as well.

```
import { shallowEqual, useSelector } from 'react-redux'

const selectedData = useSelector(selectorReturningObject, shallowEqual)
```

Regarding the your use case, you can read more right below (including other `memoize` options to reference to the same object value, when component re-calls `useSelector`):

> You may call useSelector() multiple times within a single function
> component. Each call to useSelector() creates an individual
> subscription to the Redux store. Because of the React update batching
> behavior used in React Redux v7, a dispatched action that causes
> multiple useSelector()s in the same component to return new values
> should only result in a single re-render.
>
> With useSelector(), returning a new object every time will always
> force a re-render by default. If you want to retrieve multiple values
> from the store, you can:
>
> - Call useSelector() multiple times, with each call returning a single
>   field value
> - Use Reselect or a similar library to create a memoized
>   selector that returns multiple values in one object, but only returns
>   a new object when one of the values has changed.
> - Use the shallowEqual
>   function from React-Redux as the equalityFn argument to useSelector()

[Equality Comparisons and Updates in React-Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#equality-comparisons-and-updates)

Comment: Thank you, this is all really helpful information!